# python-requests, use earlier socket

Tags: python, sockets, python-requests

Can I use socket/earlier created connection with python-requests? I don't want to waste time to make new connection to server, I just want to send another `POST` request,

```
 session.post( Url, background_callback=searchCallback,
     background_callback_args=(extraArgs,), data=' ', headers=searchHeaders,
     verify=False, timeout=0.3)
```

and then in my callback something like this

`session.getSocket().POST( ARGS )`

Comment: This is not actually a direct Requests question, it's a question about [requests-futures](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures), which is a separate project managed by the awesome [@ross](https://github.com/ross). In particular, vanilla Requests doesn't provide any form of background callback.

However, for standard Requests, you can simple continue to use the same Session object. Session performs connection pooling, so as long as the previous connection is still open (the server's choice) we'll re-use it.

Answer (score 0):

So

```
def searchCallback( session, response ):
    session.post( newUrl, data=postData )
```

will use earlier socket and won't create new one because it will be using the same [connection to server isn't closed]